# Unknown type name 'namespace' Xcode Boost

Tags: xcode, boost

I want to use boost in my Xcode project.(Xcode version 4.3.2)

I had build the boost from the MacPorts, and made the environment variables set.

But when I build the prj, there was the error:

> **Unknown type name 'namespace'**

and the error code below:

```
// This file is automatically generated. Do not edit.
// ['../../libs/compatibility/generate_cpp_c_headers.py']
// Wed Jul 23 12:11:19 2003 ('GMTST', 'GMTST')

#ifndef __CSTDDEF_HEADER
#define __CSTDDEF_HEADER

#include <stddef.h>

namespace std {
  using ::ptrdiff_t;
  using ::size_t;
}

#endif // CSTDDEF_HEADER
```

Comment: Preprocess your translation unit and see what happens there. My guess is that you've got a macro that messes up some code.

Comment: ...another guess: perhaps you forget a semicolon after some class/struct definition. Anyway, you should take a look at the preprocessed TU.

Answer (score 18):

the auto generated code is C++, not Objective-C.
Objective-C compiler rejects the invalid keyword 'namespace'.

To make it work change you project settings as follows:
- go to you Project Settings and choose the Target 
- select Build Settings -> Apple LLVM compiler X.X - Language -> Compile Sources As and set it to Objective-C++ which allows mixture of Objective-C and C++.